# Timeout exception while using Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md) in my application to store key/values.
The issue I am getting is that while fetching/checking the cache for  a key I am getting TimeOut Exception:

[image]

Here is the detailed exception:

> System.TimeoutException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233083
>   Message=Timeout performing EXISTS GlobalSettings, inst: 0, mgr:
>   ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 56, qu: 56, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq:
>   1, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=20,Free=32747,Min=2,Max=32767), clientName: WIN-VDIGHSLJUBV
>   Source=StackExchange.Redis.StrongName   StackTrace:
>          at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
>          at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
>          at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.KeyExists(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags)

I have the following code:

```
    IDatabase db = GetDatabase();
    return db.KeyExists(cacheKey);
```

and the exception I am getting is at line "db.KeyExists(cacheKey)".

Based on the issue I thought increasing timeout might help and therefore I did this in initialization:

```
redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(string.Format("{0},allowAdmin=true,syncTimeout=30000,connectTimeout=30000", redisConfig));
```

i.e I added the "syncTimeout=30000,connectTimeout=30000"

but that didn't help either.

Do I need to add timeouts to some other locations?

Do I need to look the fix for this issue at some other point of Redis logic?

Answer (score 1):

I just read through the following stack overflow post, and I think it might provide another piece of the puzzle: [StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout awaiting response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59261117/888663)

[MÇT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970115/m%C3%87t) points out that one might need to increase the minimum thread count in the application's `ThreadPool` when, as I saw in your exception message,

> WORKER: (Busy=20,Free=32747,Min=2,Max=32767)

The number of Busy worker threads is greater than the Min value, which represents the number of worker threads initially created.

*Please take a look and his answer for the specific details. This posting is a simple attempt to direct an unanswered question to actionable information.*